# Contained User working for website not for console application

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

So we have a number of databases in SQL Server set to "Partial" containment. We do this as they are part of a AAG, and it means the users can be contained in the database so when it's copied over to the other server the users are copied too.

I have the site using one such user and that works fine. However I want to point a console application at the same database using the same password. I copied the connection string but when I try to run the console application I get both the following errors logged in the event viewer:

Login failed for user 'MyUser'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: SERVERIP]

Login failed for user 'MyUser'. Reason: Password did not match that for the user provided. [Database: 'MyDatabase'] [CLIENT: SERVERIP]

If I create a login and a user in the traditional SQL way I can connect fine but then if we ever failover to the other server the login won't exist. If I create a new contained user it fails in the same way. The contained user works fine on a website running on the same server with the same connection string.

Any ideas why the console app  can't connect while the site can? It's SQL Server 2012 if that makes any difference and a .net site and console app written in C#

Comment: What type of security are you using for the web server?  Maybe application pools or are you using windows auth?  Is the web server on a different server than the sql database service?

Comment: Yeah web server on different server than SQL. I am using application pools for the sites and console app will be running as my own user, but does that make any difference if connection strings are the same? It's getting through to the DB server so don't think it can be a firewall issue.

Comment: It could be an issue if you are using windows auth.  The connection pool could be using different login than the .net app.  I have had such issues in the past and from my research many people do.  Relating to a double-hop that happens on web servers but not when you run an app.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now, I'm using SQL Server authentication so not sure if can be this.